# Angular 2 services cannot be found after aot compilation+rollup using barrels

Tags: angular, rollupjs, angular2-aot

I have a large angular2 application - works perfect in JIT mode. However, after doing AOT compilation and rollup the application doesn't work any more.

The error I'm receiving is

```
build.js:12 Uncaught ReferenceError: MyService is not defined
```

After investigating I found out that my barrel file was the cause of this problem. 
If I import the service like this:

```
import {MyService} from "../../services/index";
```

I get the error. But if I change the import statement to:

```
import {MyService} from "../../services/my-service/my-service";
```

Everything works...

Anyone knows how to fix this? I don't want to stop using barrel files...

Answer (score -1):

I'm using barrels as well and importing from them fine in version ^0.36.4.

Maybe check your version is updated to latest if you can do it.

```
import { IdentityService } from './services';
```

and in my index.ts in my services folder I have

```
export * from './user.service';
export * from './identity.service';
```

then in my NgModule declaration I add the following provider.

```
providers: [IdentityService]
```